# Exported flag keeps coming back after eclipse restart

Tags: android, eclipse, build

I have a quick question (problem). I have an android test project (made one on purpose), which has both Android dependencies, as well as Libraries set to exported in the build path. So in .classpath file I see this:

```
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.DEPENDENCIES"/>
```

Both entries have exported flag set to true. Now I want to change say Libraries to not be exported. I untick the checkbox, the .classpath file gets updated:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.DEPENDENCIES"/>
```

So far so good. However, when I restart eclipse with the same workspace, when the workspace is being processed, the classpath entry for exporting Libraries that I changed above, is resetted back to exported="true".

What is the cause of this, and most importantly, how to fix it? I'm using Eclipse 3.8.2.